# Creating many CloudWatch alerts: batch?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Does anyone have example code for creating many CloudWatch alerts simultaneously?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
$cloudWatch->put_metric_alarm(...);
$cloudWatch->put_metric_alarm(...);
$cloudWatch->put_metric_alarm(...);
// etc.
```

Between calls I'm handling errors, if any occur.

I noticed some batching code in the AWS SDK for PHP, and I'm wondering if there's a convenient way to somehow create all these in one request or create all the alarms in parallel cURL requests.

I see that [`set_alarm_state()`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonCloudWatch/put_metric_alarm) takes `returnCurlHandle` in `$opt`, from what I can gather that's the "old way" to batch up requests.